# Google Charts focusTarget: 'category' not working

Tags: charts, google-visualization, data-visualization

Google Charts `focusTarget: 'category'` works when I draw the chart in one way but not in the other one.

In the example below, the **BAR I** has a broken tooltip (not triggering the way intended) and it's working perfectly fine with the **BAR II**

```
google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages': ['corechart', 'bar']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    // _____ BAR I ______

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Form', 'Visitors', 'Starters', 'Conversions'],
        ['Form 1', 1000, 650, 490],
        ['Form 2', 485, 460, 350],
        ['Form 3', 335, 250, 105]
    ]);

    var options = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Company Performance',
            subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
            focusTarget: 'category',
        },
        focusTarget: 'category',
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('columnchart_material'));

    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));

    // ______ BAR II ______

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Form', 'Visitors', 'Starters', 'Conversions'],
        ['Form 1', 1000, 650, 490],
        ['Form 2', 485, 460, 350],
        ['Form 3', 335, 250, 105]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Company Performance',
            subtitle: 'Sales, Expenses, and Profit: 2014-2017',
        // This line makes the entire category's tooltip active.
        focusTarget: 'category',
        // Use an HTML tooltip.
        tooltip: {
            isHtml: true
        }
    };

    // Create and draw the visualization.
    new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart_material_2')).draw(data, options);

}
```

Please also take a look at [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/silverringvees/zfu8zz6m/) of the problem.

Besides different tooltip behavior, the charts also look rather different, what is the cause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one is considered a *Classic* chart, the other *Material*

*Classic* --> `google.visualization.ColumnChart` -- requires package: `'corechart'`

*Material* --> `google.charts.Bar` -- requires package: `'bar'`

*Material* charts are newer, but also **do not support** several options...

see --> [Tracking Issue for Material Chart Feature Parity](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2143)

which includes...

`focusTarget`

---

there is an option for *Classic* charts, to style them similar to *Material*

`theme: 'material'`

Comment: Thanks, and it seems like fixing these issues is not a priority...

Should probably find another charting solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the codepen link for using google charts

```
google.charts.load('visualization', '1', {
  'packages': ['corechart'],
  "callback": drawChart
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Year", "Relevance", {
      role: "style"
    }],
    ["Forward ref..", 108, "#25C16F"],
    ["Case ref..", 20, "#25C16F"],
    ["Approved", 30, "#25C16F"],
    ["Disapproved", 50, "#25C16F"],
    ["Distinguish", 25.67, "#25C16F"],
    ["Followed", 28.9, "color: #25C16F"]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1]);
  var options = {
    title: "Case Relevance",
    width: 350,
    height: 300,
    bar: {
      groupWidth: "50%",
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Relevance',
      viewWindow: {
        min: 0,
        max: 120
      },
      ticks: [0, 30, 60, 90, 120] // display labels every 25
    },

    legend: {
      position: "none"
    },
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("barchart_values"));
  chart.draw(vieenter code herew, options);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
    var row = chart.getSelection()[0].row;
    if (row == 0) {
      $("#right_panel h2").children(".small-font").html("Forward Reference in");
    } else if (row == 1) {
      $("#right_panel h2").children(".small-font").html("Case Reference");
    } else if (row == 2) {
      $("#right_panel h2").children(".small-font").html("Approved");
    } else if (row == 3) {
      $("#right_panel h2").children(".small-font").html("Disapproved");
    } else if (row == 4) {
      $("#right_panel h2").children(".small-font").html("Distinguish");
    } else if (row == 5) {
      $("#right_panel h2").children(".small-font").html("Followed");
    }
  });
}
});
```

https://codepen.io/shray04/pen/Poogmjq?editors=1000